# Best way to do error handling while executing a script using getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, python, error-handling

I have a code where I am using `getRuntime().exec()` to execute a script as:

```
            Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {

             // WHAT TO DO HERE?

            }
```

Most of the time the script will execute commands which perform some action without returning any line as in copy a file from one location to another or something on this line. I want to know how effectively can I do error handling in this case? I mean if the script returns something than in the above code those are shown as the output inside the while loop but in this case nothing is returned to be displayed. So how can I get error handling here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is jave code but not Python. You put the wrong tag.
Here are some hints for you.  Hope it helps.

```
...
// define your cmd here
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
final InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    int ch;
    try {
      while ((ch = isr.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) ch);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
t.start();
p.waitFor();
t.join();
...
```